# getting text from user in android

Tags: java, android, input, authentication

I'm trying to create a login page for an android application. The username is an email address so it contains '@'.
How can you get that email from the user in an EditText in order to verify it and check it with the database?

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
String yourString = YourEditText.getText().toString();
```

Then test the string with the database.